# How to create a Unix script to segregate data Line by Line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have some data in a MyFile.CSV file like this:

```
id,name,country                
100,tom cruise,USA          
101,Johnny depp,USA           
102,John,India
```

What will be the shell script to take the above file as input and segregate the data in 2 different files as per the country?

I tried using the FOR loop and then using 2 IFs inside it but I am unable to do so. How to do it using awk?

```
For LINE in MyFile.CSV               
Do          
If grep "USA" $LINE >0 Then  
$LINE >> Out_USA.csv         
Else         
$LINE >> Out_India.csv       
Done
```

Comment: `For`? `Do`? What shell scripting is that? Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: I suggest to remove trailing white spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this

```
grep -R "USA" /path/to/file >> Out_USA.csv
grep -R "India" /path/to/file >> Out_India.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do:
One way:

```
$ for i in `awk -F"," '{if(NR>1)print $3}' MyFile.csv|uniq|sort`; 
do 
 echo $i; 
 egrep "${i}|country" MyFile.csv > Out_${i}.csv; 
done
```

This assumes that the country name would not clash with other columns.
If it does, then you can fine tune that by adding additional regex.
For example, it country will be the last field, then you can add $ to the grep

Comment: or only `awk -F ',' 'NR>1 {print >"Out_" $3}' MyFile.CSV`